# Image Search Docker Private Registry 2

Tags: docker, docker-registry, tls1.2

I set up a secure private registry using the image registry:2. I am able to perform pull and push operations but couldn't find a method to search for an image on that registry. I was able to do the same without any issues using registry 1. While searching for a solution I came up with some links saying, image search option is not present with new docker registry2. So i would like to know details/confirmations about the following.

1. Does Docker registry API Version 2 support image search? If not why ?
2. Is there any method to communicate with a private and secure registry using API?(am getting encoded results only)

Comment: Please change formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry V2 is based on [**`docker/distribution`**](https://github.com/docker/distribution).

Its [roadmap](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/731c43e3dbe30fb87b830bab3a46d940ed649a8a/ROADMAP.md#indexing-search-and-discovery) does mention:

> The original registry provided some implementation of search for use with private registries.
>   **Support has been elided from V2 since we'd like to both decouple search functionality from the registry**. The makes the registry simpler to deploy, especially in use cases where search is not needed, and let's us decouple the image format from the registry.

This is tracked by [issue 206](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/206).

Regarding its API, [issue 5](https://github.com/banyanops/collector/issues/5#issuecomment-111315249) specifies:

> [Collector](https://github.com/banyanops/collector) now has initial support for v2. You need to give --registryproto=v2 and you also need to specify individual repositories.

Pending a full distribution API, collector might help.

Comment: as docker search doesn't support search on private registry, I decided to use registry api directly. When the registry is public(insecure without authentication) am able to get results for api calls. But when i make it secure using tls and htpassword(as mentioned in https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/ ), am getting only encoded results. is there any method to retrieve the original message at the client side? i have updated the question with details

Comment: @GayathriMenath That I do not know